# How do I find the ProtonMail Bridge PID file on my server?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, command-line-interface, service, pid

I installed Monit on my server, as well as the "ProtonMail Bridge".

I followed the following tutorial :

https://pychao.com/2020/06/10/update-on-using-protonmail-bridge-on-headless-wordpress-linux-servers/

How to know the path of the "ProtonMail Bridge" service to add it to Monit ?

ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ ps -ef

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MKbG.png)

Here is my Monit configuration. The ProtonMail Bridge party is not correct :

/var/run/fail2ban/protonmail-bridge.pid

The path of the line of code above is not good. I don't know what to wear to monitor ProtonMail Bridge.

$ sudo nano /etc/monit/conf.d/lemp-services

```
check process sshd with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
   group login
   start program = "/etc/init.d/sshd start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/sshd stop"

check process fail2ban with pidfile /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/fail2ban start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/fail2ban stop"

check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
   group www-data
   start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"

check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"

check process php-fpm with pidfile /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm stop"

check process protonmail-bridge with pidfile /var/run/fail2ban/protonmail-bridge.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/protonmail-bridge start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/protonmail-bridge stop"

check process postfix with pidfile /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
   start program = "/etc/init.d/postfix start"
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/postfix stop"

check file drupal with path /var/www/www-drupal-com/web/sites/default/settings.php
```

Comment: Is there a service at all?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I do not know. How do I know that ?

Comment: Check the files that the package installed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks but I don't know how to do this. Which order should I enter ?